# Any advice on debugging / engineering Silverlight apps that need to run in Firefox?

Tags: silverlight, firefox, plugins, crash

I'm a developer who does a lot of Silverlight work and I experience some frustrations from time to time with various browsers not playing nicely with Silverlight. Particularly, I've noticed that Firefox will frequently interact poorly with Silverlight and attack the plug-in for attempting to interact with the browser.

Specifically, I've seen various versions of Firefox crash when:

- The user initiates an action that requires clipboard access and a standard Silverlight security dialog is supposed to display. Other browsers handle this just fine.
- A Silverlight application asks the browser to display a messagebox to the user (I've since used custom Silverlight UI for this because Firefox just wasn't liking this)
- Silverlight is being run in Firefox with GoToMeeting running
- The plug-in takes a bit of time on an operation (much less of a tolerance than other browsers, but this is usually something I can do something about)
- Quite a few other times for little reason in particular

What can I do as a developer to avoid these sorts of issues for users that run Firefox? What can I do to analyze the problem when the SL plugin crashes? I don't feel that telling people to use Chrome or IE is a viable solution, but there aren't a lot of resources available on catering SL apps to run well with Firefox.

Comment: Seems to me this is an issue for the plugin and not Firefox. Doesn't Microsoft write that?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can you assuming you are [fulfilling the requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx#) is to [report these bugs](http://forums.silverlight.net/28.aspx/1?Report%20a%20Silverlight%20Bug). Although some of them sound more like Firefox bugs, like "Silverlight is being run in Firefox with GoToMeeting running".

Another workaround instead of asking your users to use another browser could be to encourage them to install the application as oob.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Firefox, if you have `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled` set to `false` in Firefox. See [bug 602502](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602502) in Bugzilla.

If you can, set it to `true`, and you should be just fine.